# How can I enable forms editing while debugging?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I searched and couldn't find an answer.

Is there any way I can enable editing of Forms while debugging in Visual Studio 2008?

Currently, when I'm debugging, all of the controls and properties are locked to prevent editing.  This is very annoying when I'm debugging and trying to adjust the forms.

Is there a setting I can change somewhere to allow this?

Comment: I don't need the change to go into effect immediately, it can wait until the next compile.  I just don't want to be precluded from making changes while I'm debugging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. All the designer state is compiled into code when you hit F5. So it is not possible to provide change in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use two instances of visual-studio, and do the edit in the 2nd instance – however try to avoid having a form open for editing in more than one instance of visual-studio.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.  Tools + Options, Debugging, Edit and Continue.  Uncheck the Enable option.  That also allows you to edit the source code without having a breakpoint active.  But of course, your changes won't have any effect until you stop and rebuild.

Comment: This allows me to edit the code, but my Form controls and properties are still locked.

Comment: Hmm, there's indeed more to it.  It isn't actually locked, you can move controls around.  But they jump right back into place.  It is also an excellent way to crash VS to the desktop, try resizing a control.  Editing the designer generated code directly is however possible.  VS2010 doesn't crash but complains that the designer file can't be changed.  It actually can.  This clearly isn't debugged well enough, you could post feedback to connect.microsoft.com